# Issue with quotes when transforming JSP variable to jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp, quotes

Here's my code

```
<c:set var="initSubjectCategories" value="${requestScope.initSubjectCategories}" scope="page" />
<c:set var="initSubjects" value="${requestScope.initSubjects}" scope="page" />
<c:set var="initRelations" value="${requestScope.initRelations}" scope="page" />
<c:set var="initComplements" value="${requestScope.initComplements}" scope="page" />
<c:set var="initComplementCategories" value="${requestScope.initComplementCategories}" scope="page" />
<c:set var="initTriplets" value="${requestScope.initTriplets}" scope="page" />

var initSubjectCategories = "${requestScope.initSubjectCategories}";
var initComplementCategories = "${requestScope.initComplementCategories}";
var initSubjects = "${requestScope.initSubjects}";
var initComplements = "${requestScope.initComplements}";
var initRelations = "${requestScope.initRelations}";
var initTriplets = "${requestScope.initTriplets}";
```

The problem is, I get an error when loading the web page, when one of those strings contains simple or double quotes.

I tried using `.replace(/"/g, '\"');` to replace double quotes with double quotes with an antislash, but it did nothing. I also tried `encodeURIComponent("${requestScope.initTriplets}")` but it did nothing either.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: appears you are trying to do escaping using javascript, need to do escaping at server

Comment: Can you tell me how to do so?

`request.setAttribute("initSubjects", subjectsToShow);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape these characters on the *server* side.  Add `escapeXml="true"` to the input tags.

If you don't do this, it gets output like:

```
<input value="valwithquo"tes"/>
```

It's too late for JavaScript to help you now because the value is `valwithquo` (and otherwise invalid html)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use escape XML inside a c:set tag???
It's not working, I get message */WEB-PAGES/Cockpit/cockpit.jsp (line: 3, column: 0) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions*